# RequireJS: Paths not resolving correctly (and differing between browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm using Coffeescript and RequireJS. I have the following RequireJS config:

```
require.config
    urlArgs: "v=0.0.7"
    baseUrl: "./src"
    catchError: true
    paths:
        "jquery": "lib/jQuery/jquery.min"
        "jqueryui": "lib/jQuery/jquery-ui.min"
        "TouchPunch": "lib/Touch-Punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min"
        "MobileEvents": "lib/jQuery/jquery.mobile-events.min"
        "MathJax": (if window.getParameter("mathJaxEnabled") == "false" then "frontend/blank" else "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_HTMLorMML")
    shim:
        "jqueryui": ["jquery"]
        "TouchPunch": ["jquery"]
        "MobileEvents": ["jquery"]
        "MathJax":
            exports: "MathJax",
            init: ->
                MathJax.Hub.Config
                    config: ["MMLorHTML.js"]
                    jax: ["input/MathML", "output/HTML-CSS"]
                    extensions: ["mml2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js"]
                    showMathMenu: false
                    showMathMenuMSIE: false
                MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload()
                return MathJax
```

My directory structure is also pretty simple. There's a src folder, which contains a folder called lib and a folder called frontend. Inside lib is a folder called jQuery (containing jquery.min.js, jquery-ui.min.js, and jquery.mobile-events.min.js), and folder called Touch-Punch (containing jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js). Inside frontend is a file called blank.js.

Everything has previously worked fine with this configuration. However, now, when I load the page, I get a script error and RequireJS complains that it cannot find Touch-Punch. Likewise, Chrome 404's:

```
GET file:///C:/repository/lib/Touch-Punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js?v=0.0.7
```

It seems RequireJS and Chrome are looking for Touch-Punch in the *root* of the repository, instead of inside the src folder. This is rather strange, because the path of Touch-Punch is fairly similar to all the other paths, and these don't error. Changing the path to `src/lib/Touch-Punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min` allows it to work fine.

I also discovered that Internet Explorer treats this problem differently still - it complains that it can't find *jQuery UI* at the location I've stated. Once again, changing the path to `src/lib/jQuery/jquery-ui.min` fixes the problem... but only in Internet Explorer. If I change that path, Chrome ceases to be able to find jQuery UI.

What is wrong with my paths to cause this? jQuery doesn't fail to load, even though its path is practically identical to jQuery UI's.

<s>The only thing I can think of is that both jQuery UI and Touch-Punch have a `-` in their filenames, but I don't see why this would cause a problem (and it never caused a problem before). Indeed, Internet Explorer can't seem to find MobileEvents either (and it also has a `-` in the filename) - but Chrome doesn't have a problem with MobileEvents.</s> Changing the filenames to have no `-` in them did not affect anything - the problem is still there.

Comment: I am aware that the title is rather awkwardly worded. If anyone can think of something better to title this question, I'd love to change it so please let me know!

Comment: Can you try renaming the things to not use '-' so we know for certain that is causing the problem?

Comment: Seems I was wrong on that guess - renamed the files and nothing changed.

Comment: Reasonably sure that there's another RequireJS conflicting with this one, so the problem isn't even in this code. I'll see if I can fix it that way before I close this question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was another RequireJS module interfering with this one. Since they're loaded asynchronously, the difference between Chrome and Internet Explorer was that the modules loaded in a different order. Part of the outer RequireJS module would load, then the inner one, *which changed the configuration of RequireJS*, and then the rest of the outer module would (fail to) load.

I fixed it by using almond to wrap the inner module.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:
Push jquery-ui into the deps of touch-punch

```
shim: {
    "jquery-ui": {
        exports: "$",
        deps: ["jquery"],
        async: false
    },
    "jquery-ui-touch-punch": {
        exports: "$",
        deps: ["jquery", "jquery-ui"],
        async: false
    }
}
```

Comment: That `jquery-ui-touch-punch` is dependent on `jquery-ui` is probably true but that's not the problem that the OP was trying to solve. The OP is reporting a problem with RequireJS not finding files due to path problems. No amount of `shim` tweaking is going to fix this. It would be appropriate to talk of dependencies in an answer that actually *solves the problem that the OP was asking*. On its own, though, this is an answer that is not answering the question asked.